# How to implement authorization in firebase cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Does Google allow to use user identification in firebase cloud functions?
If not how can we associate a user with a token/id generated by us?

Comment: Google Cloud Functions support OAuth Identity Tokens. This includes both Google User Accounts and Service Accounts.  https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using Firebase Auth, you can use [callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) to call Cloud Functions directly from your client application and they will be authenticated as the client user.

If not using Firebase Auth, you can generate [custom tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) that will allow your client applications to sign in and use rules-protected services like Cloud Firestore or Cloud Storage for Firebase.

If you don't want to do either of those, Cloud Functions are just Node.js code running in the cloud, so you can come up with another authentication/authorization scheme that makes sense for you.